# S4B Extension dialing with individual DIDs

Tags: lync, skype-for-business-2016

I'm 90% done with a migration to Skype for Business 2015.  Our organization has extensions from the legacy system that everyone has gotten to know over the years and I have to carry them over.  Many users also have DIDs.  The DIDs do not have anything to do with the extensions.

So I've got users with LineURIs like this:

> User 1: +1469XXX1234;ext=1001
>   User 2: +1469XXX5678;ext=1002

Users want to be able to dial 1002 and get User 2.  If I create normalization rules for every user like this:

> Match Pattern: ^(1001)$        Translation Pattern: +1469XXX1234;ext=$1
>   Match Pattern: ^(1002)$        Translation Pattern: +1469XXX5678;ext=$1

This works fine.  My question is, is there some way to not write a normalization rule for every user?  Looking for something like this:

> Match Pattern: ^(\d{4})$       Translation Pattern +*;ext=$1

Where the * would be treated like a wildcard and look for any user that has a LineURI with an extension that matches what was dialed regardless of their DID.  I know this syntax does not work.  It is simply to illustrate something like what I am looking for.

This seems so simple I have to be missing something.  Anyone know the secret sauce I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I reached out on the Lync forums and had a Microsoft support person confirm that unfortunately maintaining a normalization rule per extension is the only way to achieve what I am trying to do:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ecfc231c-5f79-4041-b57a-b61eda1f8777/s4b-extension-dialing-with-individual-dids?forum=lyncvoice